# How to access the /proc file system's iiterate function pointer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, rootkit

I am trying to create a simple linux rootkit that can be used to hide processess. The method I have chosen to try is to replace the pointer to "/proc" 's iterate function with a pointer to a custom one that will hide the processess I need. To do this I have to first save a pointer to it's originale iterate function so it can be replaced later. The '/proc' file system's iterate function can be accessed by accessing the 'iterate' function pointer which is a member of it's 'file_operations' structure.

I have tried the following two methods to access it, as can be seen in the code segment as label_1 and label_2, each tested with the other commented out.

```
static struct file *proc_filp;
static struct proc_dir_entry *test_proc;
static struct proc_dir_entry *proc_root;
static struct file_operations *fs_ops;

int (*proc_iterate) (struct file *, struct dir_context *);

static int __init module_init(void)
{
label_1:
    proc_filp = filp_open("/proc", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY, 0);

    fs_ops = (struct file_operations *) proc_filp->f_op;
    printk(KERN_INFO "file_operations is %p", fs_ops);

    proc_iterate = fs_ops->iterate;
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc_iterate is %p", proc_iterate);

    filp_close(proc_filp, NULL);

label_2:
    test_proc = proc_create("test_proc", 0, NULL, &proc_fops);

    proc_root = test_proc->parent;
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc_root is %p", proc_root);

    fs_ops = (struct file_operations *) proc_root->proc_fops;
    printk(KERN_INFO "file_operations is %p", fs_ops);

    proc_iterate = fs_ops->iterate;
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc_iterate is %p", proc_iterate);

    remove_proc_entry("test_proc", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

As per method 1, I open '/proc' as a file, then follow the file pointer to access it's 'struct file_operations' (f_op), and then follow this pointer to try and locate 'iterate'. However, although I am able to successfully access the 'f_op' structure, somehow it's 'iterate' seems to point to NULL. The following dmesg log shows the output of this.

```
[   47.707558] file_operations is 00000000b8d10f59
[   47.707564] proc_iterate is           (null)
```

As per method 2, I create a new proc directory entry, then try to access it's parent directory (which should point to '/proc' itself), and then try to access it's 'struct file_operations' (proc_fops), and then try to follow on to 'iterate'. However, using this method I am not even able to access the '/proc' directory, as 'proc_root = test_proc->parent;' seems to return NULL. This causes a 'kernel NULL pointer dereference' error in the code that follows. The following dmesg log shows the output of this.

```
[  212.078552] proc_root is           (null)
[  212.078567] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000003
```

Now, I know that things have changed in the linux kernel, and we are not allowed to write at various addresses (like change the iterate pointer to point at a custom function for example) and that this can be overcome by making those pages writable in the kernel, but that will come later in my attempt to create this rootkit. At present I can't even figure out how to even read the original 'iterate' pointer.

So, I have these questions :
[1] Is something wrong in the following code ? How to fix it ?
[2] Is there any other way to access the pointer to the /proc 's iterate function ?

Tested on Arch Linux running linux 4.15.7

Comment: `... somehow it's 'iterate' seems to point to NULL.` - According to the [code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/fs/proc/root.c#L188), the root directory for `procfs` filesystem has no `iterate` method; instead it has `iterate_shared` one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks.. that worked. I even progressed to hiding processes. But what about test_proc->parent returning NULL ? What is causing that ?

Comment: As far as I know, within procfs `NULL` refers to its root directory.